# Why is the force of friction in the negative $y$ direction?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

[image: https://i.imgur.com/UOwuelg.png]

[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hu_jjT4zNX4)

Why is the friction force in the negative y direction?

He comes up with the formula

$$ F = \frac{mg}{\cos(\theta) - \sin(\theta) \cdot 0.2}$$

My intuition tells me that if $\theta = 0°$ then there should be no friction and $F=mg=49.05$ N.

If $\theta = 90°$ then we only have a horizontal force, the force of friction. And this should be the biggest value because of the coefficient from friction. $F=\dfrac{mg}{0.2} = 245.25$ N.

Now if we run the function with an interval of $\theta = [0°, 90°]$ then we would get a sign switch with

$$ F = \frac{mg}{\cos(\theta) - \sin(\theta) * 0.2}$$

That doesn't seem right.

But if we would change the formula to

$$ F = \frac{mg}{\cos(\theta) + \sin(\theta) \cdot 0.2}$$

Then we get the correct values for $\theta = 0°$ and $\theta = 90°$ and the function is increasing from $\theta = [0°, 90°]$ which also seems correct.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Hi. Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example **type** questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/75633) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/75633). You might want to consider posting on [some other Physics website](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/391/75633), such as the [PhysicsForums](https://www.physicsforums.com/forums/homework-and-coursework-questions.152/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine direction of friction on a block held stationary against a vertical wall](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/199788)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with you have to understand that there can be two possible direction of frictional force. To begin with, imagine the system without friction. The typical approach to find the direction of frictional force is to find the relative motion of body (wrt the thing it is in contact with) in the absence of any friction and then, adding the frictional force to the direction opposite to the relative motion.

If you apply a force to the block with a certain angle, you can have two possible cases. One in which the vertical component of the applied force is greater than the weight of block and another in which the former is less than the latter.

For case one, friction will act downward as the net force and relative motion (of the block wrt the wall) is upward. But for the second case, friction will act upward because the net force and relative motion is downward.

However, the equations that you come up with are not general for every such cases. There can be cases where the block is at rest even when the frictional force is below its limiting value.

$$0\leq f\leq\mu N$$

So you have to consider each case differently, and you arrive at your answer depending on the data given in the question.

There can be cases where for a certain angle and block's mass you can have infinite values of $F$ for which the system is in equilibrium. This can be understood by realizing that frictional force can vary from zero to its maximum value. To solve this you will have to consider the extreme cases, where the frictional force and maximum and for all the corresponding values of $F$ the system will remain at rest.

To conclude, you cannot really come up with a general equation for these questions. You have to set some parameters constant. And as far as your question is concerned it has been provided that the $\theta =60^{\circ}$ and the block is moving upward with constant velocity, which ensures that frictional force is acting downward without any doubt. However, you aren't in the position to change $\theta$ because its a given constant.

Answer (score 1):

Friction *must* point along the surface. It exists due to the rough surfaces "gripping" into each other, trying to prevent each other from **sliding**.

And therefore it always pulls in the direction that tries to stop the sliding. The object moves upwards in your case, so friction pulls downwards. Regardless of your pushing angle.

The fact that you push inwards on the wall just makes sure that the rough surfaces can "grip" each other. Only then can friction exist.

Comment: Note that we are told that the object is moving upwards with constant velocity.

Comment: @garyp Oh darn, missed that. I will rewrite the answer. Thanks.